# Georeferenced map of Iceland Stretches

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing, mapping

I am trying to georeference a large map of iceland, and with every setting I try, the image streches out on the x axis. I have a feeling it has to do with coordnate projection, but I have tried everything I can think of (probably have tried at least 15 different crs). I have also tried every sampling method.
What else can I try to make it more of a square image like shown below?

[image: Georeferenced Image]

[image: Original Image]

[image: Settings]

Comment: Try ISN2004 / Lambert 2004 https://epsg.io/5325 [5325 in QGIS]

Comment: 4326 will make the lines of longitude vertical rather than curved leading to the stretchign

Comment: Correct on 4326, that is the issue I am having. No luck with 5325, still looks stretched for me. I am including my settings if you see any issues. https://imgur.com/a/IyUbsVy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal that your map looks streched: that what Island looks like if you set the project CRS to EPSG:4326 (check it with a basemap like OpenStreetMap). If you change the project CRS to another value (like WebMercator EPSG:3857), everything will be fine. Your "streched" georeferenced image will be transformed (again) to fit the project CRS. See here for details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814

[image]

Georeferencing only makes sense when you use the image with a software that is spatially aware. Than, it does not play a role how your image looks like in a image viewing software as the raster will be anyhow distorted in a way to fit the CRS you set in your QGIS project. So first decide there which CRS you want to use for the project (maybe using a basemap to see how shapes are distorted) and than use the same CRS as output for the Georeferencer.

You might also want to use a local CRS: see https://epsg.io/?q=Iceland%20kind%3APROJCRS

*Screenshot: I got acceptable results georefencing your image with 6 GCP-points and using Polynominal 2 transformation type and EPSG:3857: georeferenced image with OSM background map. If you change the project CRS to 4326, georeferenced image as well as OSM map will be "streched" as in your case, both both shapes will still fit :-)*

[image]

Comment: Still giving me a "stretched" image, even with project and map crs set to 3857. I had o do it with poly1 as the polynomial 2 was giving me a "failed to transform gcp" error

Comment: How does your basemap looks like in 3857? Streched as well? It should  look like above.

Comment: Got it working by referencing using map canvas and base map rather than using the points on the map. Now to just get around the weird behavior in R. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In Photoshop (or other image package) crop to the actual map
export to tiff

In QGIS load the crop tiff into the georeferencer.
Using Linear (to create a wordfile)
4 GCP points (make sure residual error is kept to a minimum)

georefence the tiff

reload into QGIS with the world file

```
50.23252856955928536
0
0
-50.00689541422411111
1427952.16767665231600404
492023.76562712574377656
```

[image]

[image]