# Cannot split vector across the 180degree line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, splitting, antimeridian

I am trying to split the vector I imported from geojson across the 180degree line and it gives me an error:

*No features were split : If there are selected features, the split tool only applies to those. If you would like to split all features under the split line, clear the selection.*

I noticed that I can split the polygon before the 180degree line but once I split it beyond it, I receive an error and cannot see a feature.

If I cut before the 180degree line (see the vertical split I did, which does not pass through 180 degrees), it splits the polygon as expected:
[image]

But, if I cut beyond the 180degree line, it returns an error:
[image]

[image]

I am using EPSG:3832 (PDC Mercator, centering the Pacific), QGIS version 3.16.1-Hannover

Has anyone encountered the same problem and know a solution?

Comment: How exactly are you splitting?

Comment: I am using the Split Features tool from the Advanced Digitizing Toolbar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-project your polygon to a pacific-centered CRS (the same you use as project CRS: `EPSG:3832`; or the same I used `EPSG:8859`) and set the project CRS to the same projection. Than you can split the polygon.

With other CRS ending at the International Date Line (like 4326), I encountered the same problem as you, as well as when I had different CRS for layer and project (3832 and 8859). See here for the [difference between layer- and project CRS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814).

*Screenshot: originally one polygon, divided with `Split Features` in several separate features. CRS is EPSG:8859 for both layer and project:*
[image]

Comment: I tried changing projection to EPSG:8859 and tried splitting but still not working

Comment: It worked! thanks! I re-projected the data into a EPSG:3832 as what I used previously so the idea is to make sure both the layer and project CRS should be the same to be able to do the split across the 180degree line. The manual guided me as well: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html#moderate-fa-saving-a-dataset-to-another-crs