# Changing origin in QGIS projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layers, print-composer, wgs84

My issue is that the QGIS print composer cannot print images that have coordinates passing beyond 180 degree in WGS84 (since it's going from -180 to 180 degree).
The area of 180 degree is in the middle of the pacific.
The CRS used does not matter, so in effect I have an inclined line running across the screen that must never appear on any print out or QGIS will crash or produce blank white prints.

Now a decent solution would be to change the origin of the projection by 90 degree, so the pacific area is "wrongly" displayed where africa or south america would be.

So changeing how layers are "wrapped" around the globe.
Is this possible?
Of course any solution allowing to do prints running across 180 degree WGS84 are also welcome.

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to do: indeed, coordinates beyond 180 degrees do not make **any** sense and cannot be located anywhere on Earth (not on a globe and not in any projection). So what is your question? Do you want to use a projection with the Pacific in the center? Can you add a screenshot to see what you try to do - and what goes wrong?

Comment: Does this help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/398090/88814 or https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396476/88814 see also here how the create a map canvas centered on the Pacific, using `EPSG:3832`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnD1m.png - consider also other Pacific centered CRS like e.g. `EPSG:8859`

Comment: Coordinates beyond 180° WGS seem to happen if I scroll eastward from Wake Island. At some point rendering stops and QGIS crashes. Same if I go westward from Hawaii. If I try to print a map of this region between Wake Island and Midway, the print process either crashes QGIS or the result PNG/print is blank white or partially white.
I need to make several detailed prints of the area in ESRI 102030. A Lambert conic CRS for this area.

Thanks for the links, I will read thru them.