# Calculating distances between a set of coordinates

Tags: qgis, measurements

I'm using QGIS 3.2, WGS 84, EPSG 4326.    I have a series of coordinates that represent the location of Red Squirrel trail cams in a Forest, there is another file with every sighting date and location listed over several years.  I am trying to derive an estimate of the total population of Red Squirrels.  I would like to compare sightings within each 24 hour period taking into account the distance between other sightings on the same day thus eliminating 2 sightings where the squirrel could have travelled to second point.  I hope to establish the max distance a squirrel can travel from another data file of radio collared tracking with date/time/location data.

However I first need to be able to calculate distances from the cordinates but am unsure how to do this accurately.

Comment: This is trivially done with any GIS application, and a partial differential equation only solvable through iterative means if you want to do it on your own (search on "second problem of geodesey")

Comment: See this here for how to measure distances in QGIS: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/408399/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/401377/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396041/88814

Comment: It may be trivial to an expert but to a non mathematically minded beginner it is non trivial, hence asking question.  Am reading all the links suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at the concept of [coordinate systems and transformations](https://learn.opengeoedu.de/tutorials/OGE-Tutorial_KNE_Koordinaten-en.pdf) to have your data in an "Cartesian Coordinate System" like UTM and transform your geographic point locations for **metric euclidian distance measurements**.

To start with the capabilities of QGIS the [Lesson: Reprojecting and Transforming Data](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html) and [Nearest Neighbor Analysis](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/nearest_neighbor_analysis.html) could be a good start point.