# Filtering OSM natural peaks in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, filter

The primary source of data for a map that I'm making in <s>QGIS 3.14</s> QGIS 3.20 is OSM.
There is a layer which contains natural peaks, obtained with a `natural=peak` query.

In order to reduce clutter, I'd like to **only display a particular peak if it's the highest peak in a 5km radius**. Is there a plugin that can help me achieve this, or some OSM query magic that would yield the same result?

#### (EDIT) What I've tried so far:

After suggestions from @Babel, I tried a couple of things.

I updated to QGIS 3.20.0-Odense and this is the version I'll be using from now on. This is the latest version available and contains functions such as `overlay_nearest` and `array_max`.

Since OSM data has the elevation data stored in the `ele` field as a string, I used the Field Calculator to create a new field called `ele_int` based on `to_int(to_real(ele))` expression.

I had to first clean up and fix data fields that contained elevations such as `123m` and `` 1`234 `` manually, as well as delete entries which didn't contain any elevation information in the `ele` field.

Then I tried using select by expression using the following:

```
array_max (
        overlay_nearest( 
            @layer, 
            ele_int, 
            limit:=100, 
            max_distance:=1000
        )
) > ele_int
```

But this results in 4122 peaks selected out of 4152 in total.
Interestingly, if I change `max_distance` to 10 or 50000, I still get 4122 selected rows, so `max_distance` doesn't affect the result.

(Hindsight: because there was a mismatch between the feature layer CRS and the project CRS, I had to use `max_distance` value of 0.08 in order to get the needed result)

One thing that does impact results is changing the `limit` in the expression, so if the limit is set to 1000, then 4149 peaks are selected, and if the limit is set to 10, then 3890 peaks are selected, but this doesn't give me the results that I need.

In the image below, you see the selection results. This tight group of 6 peaks is at least 14km away from the nearest peak outside of the group, so I'm using it to verify my results. The distance between the top left two peaks is approximately 2400 meters. It doesn't matter whether max_distance is set to 10, 1000, or 50000, I always see all 6 of these peaks selected. I've also verified that map unit is set to meters.

[image: Select by expression results]

It feels like I'm very close to the goal but can't quite figure out the last bit. One thing I found interesting is that if I set the `max_distance` to `100000` (100 km), and the `limit` to `1`, only one feature gets selected, and I would expect to see more. It feels almost like the expression is not performed for each feature, but only for one?

#### (EDIT 2) Additional findings about overlay_nearest

When I add a label to each peak for debugging so that every peak is labeled as `to_string("ele_int") + ' - ' + array_to_string(overlay_nearest(@layer, "ele_int", limit:=5, max_distance:=100))`

This is the result:
[image]
Note that overlay_nearest returns values while completely disregarding the distance to nearest point (the distance between each of these points is >2km). Also note that the first member of the array is the point itself, and the second point in the array is the closest one.

Either I'm using `overlay_nearest` wrong (more likely), or this could be a bug in QGIS (less likely).

#### (EDIT 3)

I start seeing the effects of max_distance when it's set to a very low value. In practice, I get results that I'd like to see when it's set to 0.07 (corresponds to around 5-10 km). Could it be the CRS I'm using (EPSG:32634)? The distance measurement tool gets the distance correctly though...

#### Final thoughts

The accepted answer works well. The problem I am seeing seems to be due to CRS mismatch between the feature layer and the project. It's possible even in this case to make things work by choosing a very small value for `max_distance`, something like 0.08.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QGIS expressions to check for each peak if it has another, higher peak within a radius of 5 km or not. Make a selection based on this and delete the peaks with at least one peak that is higher within a radius of 5 km.

You need QGIS 3.16 or later for the [`overlay_nearest`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/de/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?#overlay-nearest) function. From today, [QGIS 3.20 is available for download](https://blog.qgis.org/2021/06/22/qgis-3-20-odense-is-released/), so I would recomand to get this version installed.

Let's suppose you have a point layer with the attribute `hight` (otherwise adapt the name in line 5 and the last line). Use select by expression with this expression:

```
array_last ( 
    array_sort(
        overlay_nearest( 
            @layer, 
            hight, 
            limit:=100, 
            max_distance:=5000
        )
    )
)> hight
```

If you use QGIS 3.18 or higher, you could replace the first two lines by [`array_max(`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?#array-max) and delete the last closing bracket `)` in the second last line.

If you download peaks from OpenStreetMap, the field `ele` with elevation values comes formatted as string and some values are empty. Furthermore, there are integer values and decimal ones mixed. You could make the conversion directly in the expression above, but it could get confusing, so I advice first to create new field `hight` with field calculator with the following expression and than using this newly calculated field as input for the above expression:

```
if (ele ='',0,to_int(to_real(ele)))
```

*Screenshot: Select by expression selects all points that have a higher peak within 5 km (yellow points) - delete them; the remaining points are the highest peaks within 5 km. For correct distance measurements, be sure to have your layer in an appropriate CRS:*

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of the "select by expression" feature, nor was I familiar with the scripting language. This answer worked for me.

Comment: I do have a problem with this kind of query - it works the same regardless if I set max_distance to 1 or 100000. Changing the limit does work and give different results. The map unit is set to meters. @Babel do you have any idea why? I updated to QGIS 3.20 in the meantime.

Comment: Can you provide sample data? Which QGIS version do you use? Be sure to have 3.16 or later - and if you use the version with `array_max`, you must have 3.18 or later. When I test it, the result changes with different values for `max_distance`.

Comment: I used QGIS 3.20, and the data I use can be reproduced by importing openstreetmap data using the ```natural=peak``` query. To that data, I apply the select by expression, and I do not use ```array_max``` but instead the ```array_last``` and ```array_sort``` sequence.
I'm now going to check with 3.16 LTR.

Comment: For what it's worth, I get the same results with QGIS 3.16. The number of selected points doesn't change when changing max_distance.
```array_last ( 
    array_sort(
        overlay_nearest( 
   @layer,
            expression:=ele, 
            max_distance:=5000,
            limit:=100
        )
    )
)> ele```

Comment: OK, I now see the problem: when you download OpenStreetMap data, you have a field `ele` for elevation. It is, however, formatted as `string` (text), not as number, so that's why it doesn't work. You have to convert the values to a integer format first. You could do it directly in the expression, however I would recomand creating a new attribute `elevation` with field calculator because you also have empty values that can create problems. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: What I did so far:
- I used the Field Calculator to add a field called ele_int, and I used the expression ```to_int(to_real(ele))``` to populate it
- Then I tried selecting by ```array_max``` of ```overlay_nearest``` on ```ele_int``` instead of ```ele``` and I still can't get it to work. I'll update my question with more details. Thank you for helping :)

Comment: Unmarked as accepted answer. I feel we are on the right track but in the current form, this solution still doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: OK, so I guess best would be if you could provide your data (+ your project file, if possible). It's difficult to see what went wrong in your case using my own project and data - in my case, everything works fine. So there must be some setting, but from far, it's difficult to guess.

Comment: Your peak-layer from OpenStreetMap is probably still in `EPSG:4326`, isn't it? You changed the project CRS, but not the layer CRS to `EPSG:32634`. That would explain why changing the `max_distance` has no effect. Be sure to properly understand the difference between layer and project CRS, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814

Comment: It seems that this is exactly the problem (although the distance tool gets distances right). In any case, your answer covers everything in case someone else finds themselves in a similar situation. My problem is solved by choosing a very small distance as a workaround, but does exactly what I need. Thank you for the help, I learned a lot from this!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't confuse distance tool on the map canvas and the distances used to calculate distances for each layer! Also don't confuse planimetric (cartesian) and ellipsoidal distances. That's why you get different distances.