# Point data appears in middle of ocean but CRS is same across layers using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have seen similar questions, have followed the advice, and still can't get it to work.

I am trying to add point data to a map. I have set my map and data layer to the same CRS (WGS 84), but still my point data is in the middle of the ocean. I am using a very recent version of QGIS, and my understanding is 'on the fly' projections are already enabled, so I am stuggling to understand why this won't line up. I am using a shapefile of medieval diocese I got off the internet and lat/long coordiates.

[image: Attribute table]  [image: map]

I can get it to work if I set my map layer to UTM 30N, and use UMT coordinates, but some of my data falls into UTM 31N, so I have 2 datasets for the point data, which is less than ideal!

I am fairly new to GIS.

[image: Correct Map layers]

[image: Corect map image]

Comment: When you say you set your layers to the same CRS, what exactly did you do?

Comment: You need to swap your X and Y. Should be Y(Lat): 51.296,X(Long): -2.235

Comment: Please provide links to at least one of the previous questions so you can show how its/their advice does not work for you.

Comment: Did you try to add a basemap in the background to check if your polygon layers are in the correct position? You say you "set my map layer to UTM 30N" - did you somehow change (set) the layer's CRS? ***Never*** do that (if you're not 100% sure about what you're doing), see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814 and to understand the difference of layer vs. project CRS: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814

Comment: @Pointdump - so simple! I had tried that after reading a different comment, but obviously I didn't do it correctly. I amended the dataset in my question and another dataset and your solution has worked perfectly. Thankyou so much :)