# QNEAT3 Shortest Path works but OD Matrix doesn't

Tags: qgis, qgis-network-analysis

I have successfully created a shortest path layer using QNEAT3. When I try and use the OD Matrix from layers as lines (M:N) i get NULL values.

My network layer is correct (as it works for shortest path) and has no errors (tested using Geometry Checker).

I have two other layers that contain a unique id and a lat and long column amongst other columns

The network is in CRS 27700 and the origin and destination are in CRS 4326. I have tried changed the CRS to either 4326 for network or 27700 for origin and destination and this doesn't work.

I have also tried using different Topology tolerances, but with no joy.

Below is the inputs i'm using for OD Matrix from layers as lines (m:n).

[image]

I'm using QGIS 3.16.2 Hannover and QNEAT 1.0.4

My Origin layer is as follows:

[image]

My Destination layer is as follows:

[image]

My dataset is much larger, I have used the Vector Selection/Random Extract to reduce the dataset for testing.

I have also followed the below tutorial, which worked fine:

https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/origin_destination_matrix.html

Comment: You "have tried to change the CRSand this doesn't work". How / what did you do exactly? And what means "didn't work" - **what** did not work?

Comment: @Babel I changed the CRS in Properties/Source/Assigned Coordinate Reference System. By didn't work i mean i got the same results, NULL values for the 'costs'. I also tried changing it in the Project Properties. The Network values dissapeared from the maps when I changed them to 4326

Comment: You "changed" the CRS in layer properties? Never do that! See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814 - use Reproject instead of that: right click layer / export /save and in the export dialog, you can choose the CRS you want the layer to reproject to.

Comment: Thank you @Babel that has now worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRS 4326 is a simple lat -lon-System, not a projected one. Try saving this layer as a projected system ( crs 27700 ) and reload this new shape-file and now run your analysis again.