# QGIS: Changing the CRS Coordinates on an XYZ Tile (Google Satellite Image)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, vector, xyz-tiles

**Problem**

Firstly, I am a complete novice to QGIS and I have only been using this software for one week. Therefore, I apologise if I am not using the correct terminology. I have added vector layers **(ESRI shapefiles)** for the country of **Iceland** showing railroads, water bodies, and roads. The coordinate system for my vector data is **WGS 84/UTM zone 27 N** **(see images 1 and 2).**

**Image 1:**

[image: Image of my CRS selection]

**Image 2:**

[image]

I have found a **'Google Satellite'** image that I downloaded from **Hatari labs** (below).

[Location of Google Satellite Image](https://hatarilabs.com/ih-en/how-to-add-a-google-map-in-qgis-3-tutorial)

I have created a **new connection** and produced an **XYZ Tile** from this 'Google Satellite' image. When I add the XYZ Tile layer to my map, the resolution and scale are acting really strange. My vector layers of Iceland are laying on top of Greenland instead of being in the ocean, and I don't know how to correct this issue **(see image 3).**

Overall, this XYZ tile is supposed to **imitate image 4** (see below), which is demonstrated in my tutorial. My tutor is not available right now to advise, although, he sent me an email suggesting that this is a CRS issue.

**Does anyone know how to change the CRS coordinate system for XYZ tiles to be identical to my vector data (WGS 84/UTM zone 27 N)?**

I'm very confused!

**Image 3:**

[image]

**Image 4:**

[image]

Comment: Right-click on the XYZ tile -> Properties -. CRS and select Project CRS or choose the one you need.

Comment: Hello MKR. Many thanks for your reply, it was deeply appreciated. Even if I change the CRS to be identical to my vector data, the scale and positioning of my vector data of Iceland in contrast to where it should correctly positioned on the Google Satellite image is still wrong. Can you offer anymore pearls of wisdom?

Comment: Was the initial 'Google Satellite' image displayed in the right location on the map?

Comment: The tutorial asked us to take the XYZ tile address from Hatari Labs so I am not sure: https://hatarilabs.com/ih-en/how-to-add-a-google-map-in-qgis-3-tutorial

Comment: MKR's suggestion was very misleading and probably made the problem worse. Before changing CRSs you have to know exactly what and why you would change. Did you change *anything* related to CRS in this process? Do the layers overlay correctly if you load the Google layer and your Iceland data in a new project?

Comment: My answer was deleted as requested. This is all I can help with for now. Hope someone else will sort out your problem.

Comment: Bugmerlot123, I have not been able to overlay both layers for the vector data and the 'Google Satellite' image to align, I am still trying. Do you have any suggestions? Many thanks if you can help

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814 to understand what went wrong and how to avoid that.