# QGIS converting my coordinates erroneously

Tags: qgis, coordinates, convert, wgs84, utm

I have a set of data in CSV format where the first, second and third columns are Point #,Coord of X and Coord of Y respectively (in UTM Zone 51N). Then I added a delimited text layer in QGIS 3.16.5 and imported my CSV file there, setting the correct CRS to UTM Zone 51N as well as the correct geometry definition for the X & Y fields.

Now, when I try to export the newly added layer, I set the format to CSV and set the CRS to WGS84 (since I want it to convert from UTM Zone 51N to WGS 84), set the geometry to AS_XY and then clicked "OK".

When I opened the outputted CSV file, it turns out it created 2 new columns for the supposedly new converted WGS84 coordinates but the result is far from the actual value of what is really the correct coordinate.

I followed every YouTube tutorial but my QGIS is just converting it wrong. How or where in the process did I get it wrong?

Comment: Please provide exemplary coordinates after export, as well as the EPSG-codes you used.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the most common question here (QGIS flavor). When you "set the CRS to WGS84", you likely clobbered the correct spatial reference.  Instead, you want to *set* to the actual PCS, then *project* it to WGS84 decimal degrees.

Comment: What do you mean by exemplary coordinates? I'll try to look on the EPSG-codes tomorrow, im currently resting now. Thanks

Comment: How do i do that? The PCS to project to WGS84?...and what is PCS?

Comment: PCS is short for Projected Coordinate System. The EPSG code for UTM 51N in WGS84 is EPSG:32651, according to [this website](https://epsg.io/32651).

Comment: Ok thank u for providing the meaning of that acronym. But my problem still Exist. Still how do i solve it?

Comment: @Erik the EPSG code to UTM Zone 51N is EPSG:32651

Comment: When you import the points: are they in the correct location on the globe (add a basemap to check)? If so, please describe your workflow a bit more detailed: where do you "set" the CRS? See also: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814