# Viewshed error QGIS

Tags: qgis, viewshed, attributeerror

I'm a newbie to SE (and to QGIS), wondering if you could give me a hand with an error I don't know how to fix.

I am doing a vis analysis in QGIS, viewshed keeps showing the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetProjection'`. My DTM layer and my viewpoint are now in the same CRS, same metric system.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide more details (e.g. the CRS you use) and a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks! The lidar WMS came originally in WGS84 Pseudo-mercator (which was in degrees), so I changed the project's CRS to ETRS89/ UTM zone 30N. I seem unable to upload screenshots here? :S

Comment: Edit the initial question and add the information there. There, you can alos upload screenshots. By the way: Pseudo-Mercator is **not** in degrees. Better add EPSG-codes to make clear what CRS you have. As you mention degrees and WGS84, I guess it is `EPSG:4326`.

Comment: 1: Do **not** "change" CRS - never (if you're not 100% sure about what you do and why). See here for details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814 - always make sure with a basemap in the background that the layer is in the correct location. 2: You can't use a WMS layer for processing. Try to download the Digital Terrain model.

Comment: Many thanks for all your help here. It was the WMS layer, of course.