# Scale reference changes significantly when reprojected from GCS to PCS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, vector, scale

I am using QGIS throughout this whole process.

I have a varied selection of open-sourced African spatial data (i.e. [municipalities throughout Africa](https://earthworks.stanford.edu/catalog/stanford-nt680nw4634)) that I have been trying to reproject from their original CRS (*EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic*) to any new Projected CRS:
[image]

After which, the spatial data is severely altered in scale from its original (**1:7000000**) to its output (**1:92** - **1:169**).
[image]

[image]

- I have tried both "On The Fly" Reprojection, as well as right-clicking the layer and selecting the new CRS manually for each layer,
- I have tried using the `Fix Geometries` tool to rectify this problem but that makes little-to-no difference in the results.

Comment: Looks like you did not reproject but simply reassign a coordinate system, this changed the unit degree to unit meter.

Comment: It looks like you have a coordinate system problem, see if any of the suggestions at https://ihatecoordinatesystems.com/ help.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814