# Clip raster by mask layer

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a raster image of Mediterranean zone, and I want to clip it by a mask layer but I think the raster is not displayed correctly. It's bigger than others and the mask does not cover the desired area.

[image]

Comment: It means that either your mask or your raster have a wrong CRS. You should give more details, if you want us to help.

Comment: @katagena I downloaded the raster as HDF format, when I open it in QGIS I get the "the raster has no coordinate reference system set" icon, so I chose one (WGS 84 EPSG:4326) (the icon disappeared) but when I add the mask layer of the same CRS I get what displayed in the image above

Comment: Where did you get your data? Can you post a link?

Comment: @Pointdump from terrascope (SPOT VGT) https://services.terrascope.be/download/SPOTVGT/C3/S10/V2/

Comment: @Pointdump services.terrascope.be/download/SPOTVGT/C3/FreeS10/V2/2012/20120421/2_20120421S10_Europe_RADIO/2.20120421S10_Europe_B3.HDF (this is the link to download the image above)

Comment: And the mask? Where did you get it?

Comment: @katagena I created it, and I clipped with it other rasters (Sentinel and Landsat) and it worked

Comment: Do **never** simply "choose" a CRS - this results in the kind of problems you have. If CRS is not recognized, you have to find the correct CRS - the one the date was created in. See here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814 and here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814