# Projection or Georeferencing Problem

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

[image]

I'm having a strange thing happen when I try to overlay NY State data on the Google Satellite imagery from the QMS on QGIS. All the projections agree but NY ends up in the Mediterranean.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Please, specify all data sources and their projection.

Comment: The coordinates in the pictures are **not** in 4326... values around there would be close to `5W; 40N`. Chances are you have set (instead of reproject) the data CRS.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814 to understand what happens. To correct the situation, you must find out the original CRS the data initially was created in. If you have to original data source, simply create a new project and load the data to it and look in layer properties what CRS the layer was created in.