# Point layer is not projecting on the correct location in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, vector

I have two shapefiles both projecting on EPSG:28351 GDA94 MGA Zone 51, one is in polygon and the other one is in points. Points should be sitting on top of the polygons but when I load these two layers in QGIS, the polygon one works fine but the points are projected on the South Pole.

Surely there is something wrong with the projection but I have tried a couple of times and still couldn't set it in the correct location.

Can anyone give me some help on how to fix this?

Comment: Please post your data.

Comment: The first step: check the *.prj* file for both shapefiles, they shall match. The second step: ensure that they were correctly imported, e.g. no changes in the CRS were applied. The third step: maybe extraction of these files from original source was done wrongly, try to get these shapefiles again, with the proper export procedure.

Comment: Did you somehow manually "set" the CRS? You should not do that, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814

Comment: Thanks Guys, I've figure out what went wrong, it's when I exported the shapefile from Manifold I did don't manually assign a CRS so the CRS is wong when I exported, I did the export again with the correct CRS now it's all working fine : )