# Setting Layer CRS sends layer to wrong location

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, georeferencing

I have a recurring problem where setting a layer's CRS sends the layer to the same incorrect location. WGS84 sends the layer to the ocean south of West Africa. British National Grid sends the layer to the ocean off the coast of Cornwall. It's done this with multiple layers including one I georeferenced myself (If I upload that layer it goes to the correct location automatically but adding a CRS will once again send it to one of the two wrong locations I just mentioned).

This must be a user error of mine to be producing the same results so consistently. Has anyone had this same thing happen? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do **not** "change" (set) the layer CRS! Never do that - unless you exactly know what you do. Do **reproject** the layer instead. See here for that: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814

Comment: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5300/2856

Comment: Neither is working for me. The reproject plugin says "layer not found" and the export method just gives me another Tiff which has no CRS when I add it to the canvas and therefore needs a CRS assigned to it which again sends the data south of West Africa.