# Why does the UK look different in some maps?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, united-kingdom

Sometimes when I create maps the UK seems to look like it's tilted back, other times it appears "flat". The projections are the same (OSGB 1936 / British National Grid).

I am using QGIS.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: **What** is in British National Grid? The data (layers)? Or the project? Looks like you have different project CRS and thus data in the same CRS is transformed on the fly to match the project CRS. See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814

Comment: This look like two different projection, by "the same" did you mean that you have two layer with the same projection or the same layer in two project using the same projection ?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/977/

Comment: If data is the same, the difference would be in the crs of the QGIS canvas.  QGIS will automatically reproject your data to fit the projection of the canvas.

Comment: `Leaning back` looks like EPSG:4326 map canvas, `looks flat` looks like EPSG:27700 map canvas

Comment: The Transverse Mercator Projection is the reason  "The transverse version is widely used in national and international mapping systems around the world".

Comment: Hi, In one session of QGIS I changed the from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:27700 and that seemed to work change what I can see on the canvas to "flat". On another it stayed the same :-( Have changed everything I can see that might have something to do with projections - the box in bottom right and on the layer (properties->Source->Assigned (... CRS) and that doesn't seem to change anything.