# Coordinate System Alignment - Two features - different systems - yet they align

Tags: qgis

Using QGIS - I have two feature layers that look to be in alignment.  Yet they do not share the same coordinate system.  When I switch one layer to the same coordinate system so that they both match, they no longer align.  I need them to share the same coordinate system so that I can Clip.

Comment: Please read up on `on the fly reprojection` and be advised, that `clip` works usually flawlessly with data in different CRS.

Comment: I keep getting "Intersection failed" when trying to clip.  Assumed it was the mismatch.

Comment: To bring different layers to the same projection (CRS), you must **reproject** them: e.g. right-click layer > export and in the export settings, select the CRS you want to reproject to. For background, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814

Comment: I reprojected using the export method  - this worked.  But clip still failing with same error.

Comment: Have you made sure their geometries are valid? Is at least one (the second) of your layers a polygon?

Comment: I ran 'check validity' and both feature layers have 0 errors, and 0 invalid.   One is US counties.  One is a large polygon.  Trying to clip US counties to identify which are within the large polygon.

Comment: So probably sharing your data would be a good option.

Comment: Would be happy to share the zip folder with two feature layers...best method?