# How to get Amersfoort 28992 in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, gdalwarp

I am currently analysing landscape change in the Netherlands, for which I am using maps which have Amersfoort 28992 as their standard CRS. However the most recent map uses Amersfoort 4289 instead.
For my analysis I need to change the raster resolution of the most recent map, which I was planning to do with the align raster function under the raster tab. This doesn't work as the CRS do not match each other. I am not able to change the latest map from 4289 to 28992. If I change the 28992 map to 4289 it's not projected on the same place anymore. What would be the best way to go from here?

Comment: Have you tried reprojecting one of the datasets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You hit the already classical problem: do **not** change the layers's CRS, instead use Menu <kbd>Raster</kbd> > <kbd>Projections</kbd> > [`Warp (reproject)`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterprojections.html#warp-reproject) (in case of raster layers).

Alternatively, you could have the same effect by exporting/saving the layer and in the export dialog choose the new CRS.

See here for background about the difference between chaging layer CRS and reprojecting: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814

Comment: Saving the layer and changing the CRS to Amersfoort 28992 RD new seems to have done the trick already! I haven't tried the warp function yet, but will do that as well, as it is my first time working with raster's it seems wise to understand the warp tool as well. Thanks a lot!