# Issue with GPKG imported in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am starting to use QGIS and have been struggling to get a GPKG package to sit properly.
This package contains the London conservation are information, which can be downloaded from the link below:
https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/conservation_areas

I see that the GPKG specifies a specific CRS, which is :
Projection: EPSG:27700, British National Grid

So I have created a new project in QGIS (version 3.32.3-Lima) with that same EPSG value in the project CRS option, but when I import the GPKG information it doesn't seem visible in the project.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have no problem loading this file in the correct location. Try this: Open a new project, don't change any CRS, load a basemap (e.g. OpenStreetMap from XYZ tiles) and then load the Geopackage (e.g. drag and drop to the QGIS window). It should be in the correct location. Zoom to this layer, then change the project CRS to 27700.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the screenshot (upload it, not as a wetransfer link)

Comment: Hi Babel,Many thanks for your answer. I tried that but it propmted me with a red warning, see link to screenshoot below I was wondering if you know what this could be and, if you were able to do it, could you share that qgis file with the plan inserted? I am trying to finish this for a presentation in a few hours and any help would be great, many thanks in advance :)                                                                                                                                        
  [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcEST.jpg

Comment: Open a new project and drag the geopackage in, there should be no other steps needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the layer's CRS is not correctly recognized. When loading the layer to an empty project, I get the same error you describe in the comments.

To solve it, proceed as follows:

1. Create a new, empty project
2. Load an OpenStreetMap basemap form XYZ tiles
3. Drag and drop the layer to QGIS
4. Right click layer > <kbd>Layer CRS...</kbd> > <kbd>Set Layer CRS...</kbd>. In the dialog window that opens, select British National Grid `EPSG:27700`.

Then the layer appears in the correct place. I exported this layer again in `EPSG:27700` as well as in Web Mercator `EPSG:3857` - you both layers + project file [can be downloaded here](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/8ooMOpk6hP7Z1kV).

Be aware: normally, **don't change the layer's CRS**, see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814) why and for some background.

*Here how it looks when loading the initial layer: both layer's CRS and project CRS are unknown or unnamed:*

[image]

When you load the initial layer you linked to an empty QGIS project, the project CRS will be undefined as the layer's CRS is not recognized and QGIS uses the CRS of the first loaded layer to define the project CRS. So from there, you got a whole bunch of problems. That's why in such cases always load a background layer first. You can always change the layer CRS later by clicking the icon at the bottom right of your QGIS window.

Comment: Hi Babel - that was so useful, many thanks for sharing it, it solved the problem! I tried to ochange the CRS before for project and layers, but dragging the GPKG in a blank project and add the rest of the information afterwards did the trick.