QGIS reprojection of layers with differing CRS
My problem is very similar to Changing unit of measure from degrees to meters in QGIS?.
I use a baseline map with EPSG:3857 WGS 84 pseudo-mercator CRS whose units is meters.
In addition I use a polygon layer with LAMB93-RGF93 lambert CRS whose units is also in meters.
I have a point shapefile with EPSG:4326-WGS 84 which has geographic (lat/lon) units.
The CRS of my project has been automatically set as IGNF:LAMB93
The result is the image bellow:

I need to perform an IDW operation on the point shapefile which means it should be reprojected into a CRS with "meters" units. But when I try to change its CRS to any other CRS it will be shifted to another point on the planet.

You won't want to use  EPSG:3857 as the meters are also 'pseudo'.

Can you specify the name of the tool you are using? Normally, if you use "Reproject Layer" (Vector general), you should be fine.

It sounds like you are changing the CRS in the layers properties.  This would only affect the display of the data.  Try saving the file as a new file into the CRS of your choice.

Do NOT "change" the CRS, but reproject. See here for details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814

@nmtoken Thanks for this clarification. As the matter of fact I randomly selected this basemap from the long list of available basemaps. I do not have any Idea based on what criteria should I set a basemap for my project. Sometimes I set Google Map Satellite and sometimes I use ESRI ...

To create a new vector layer in the desired CRS, you should use the Reproject layer tool.
Raster layers are reprojected with GDAL's Warp (reproject).
You can change the CRS of your project in the Project properties.
There seem to have been different versions of RGF93-Lambert93. EPSG is 2154.
